# Wacom Tablet - Photoshop stop brush size changing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing-tablet, wacom

In photoshop I'd like to be able to use my wacom to draw straight lines by the click-shift-click method but the brush size changes from large to very small as it would it was pressure related. Has anyone found at solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Disable the **Shape** dynamic on the **Brush Panel**.

[image]

I believe it's on by default.

It's the `Size Jitter` there which causes a brush to change size as you paint.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmT63uYaJbA) a video that goes into the details, but basically you need to disable shape dynamics. There's a button in the command bar that does that:[image]

You can also disable it in the brush settings panel by setting the size control to off:
[image]